# Multiple instances vs one instance with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-management, kendo-ui

I am building a Kendo UI application that has several (20+) different kendoWindows.  I'm wondering if performance will become a concern if I instantiate an instance for each of them on DOM load.

Would it be better to instantiate only when one is needed and then kill it when it's closed.

The third option I was considering was to instantiate one kendoWindow and just change it's params and content when opened.

I guess what I'm wondering is whether or not the first method will make an impact on performance and whether or not one of the other two methods would be a better idea.

Here's my code:

```
// Initialize all the dialogs.
    function _initializeDialogs( ){
        // that.dialogs is an object literal filled with jquery objects.
        var dialogs = that.dialogs;

        var defaults = {
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            visible: false,
            open: setCenter
        }

        // Iterate over the dialogs and initialize each one as kendoWindows.
        for ( dl in dialogs ){
            // Assign that.dialogs[dl] to a variable.
            var dialog = dialogs[ dl ];

            // If DOM element exists.
            if( dialog ){
                // If Dialog jquery element is not already a kendoWindow.
                if( !dialog.data( 'kendoWindow' ) ){
                    // Instantiate the kendoWindows.
                    dialog.kendoWindow( defaults );
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Well...you could take a look at the console and watch how long it takes for the DOM to become ready...and then you could discern for yourself if it's better or worse...hard to say sitting over here across the world...

Comment: I guess it's a question more about best practice and scalability in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Third option will be the best one as you have only one window to manage and the contents are provided as input param, this is a good solution in this scenario.